# Can I use linqToXml to transform an existing xml doc?

Tags: c#, linq

Can I use linqToXml to transform an existing xml doc? Can someone provide an example?

Basically I want to load an xml doc and replace an existing node with another node.

Thanks

To

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [this](http://www.xmlplease.com/update-xml-linq) will help you